# MySQL GROUP BY and MAX() error

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

My table looks like:

```
id  |  invoice  |  newlevel   |   status
----------------------------------------
1   |  123      |  1          |  
2   |  123      |  2          |  2abc
3   |  555      |  1          |  
4   |  123      |  3          |  3xyz
5   |  555      |  2          |  2abc
6   |  999      |  5          |  5YYY
```

How do I

```
SELECT invoice, MAX(newlevel) AS currentlevel FROM example GROUP BY invoice
```

When I execute the query, it returns

```
id  |  invoice  |  currentlevel   |   status
----------------------------------------------
4   |  123      |  3              |   
5   |  555      |  2              |   
6   |  999      |  5              |   5YYY
```

The column status seems to be the first result (from id = 1), the other data is correct.

I tried everything like union multiple querys, then group by or subquerys in 3 level.

**UPDATE:** @Barmar was right, this is an duplicate. My solution was the Answer from @Kevin Burton [in the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745679/3236231)

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 WHERE (id,rev) IN 
( SELECT id, MAX(rev)
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY id
)
```

Comment: Your query doesn't have `id` or `status` in it, why is that in your result?

Comment: You didn't specify which row the `status` should come from, so it can come from any row in the group. It doesn't have to come from the same row with `MAX(newlevel)`.

Comment: @user3236231 try this SELECT invoice, (newlevel) AS currentlevel FROM example GROUP BY invoice having max(newlevel)

Comment: @RakeshKumar That's even wronger than what he tried.

Comment: what result do you want..

Comment: Hi, the additional results (id, status) dont come from query. This result is an example.

I want the result  5 |  555 | 2  | 2ABC